# A string of words illustrating the subtle differences between vowel phonemes

Tags: pronunciation

The large number of vowel phonemes in English makes learning pronunciation difficult. I am looking for a string of simple words that highlights the differences between the vowels.

For example, *bad*, *bed*, *bid*, and *bead* differ only in their vowels. Arranged with a decreasing openness of the vowels, the subtle differences are more noticeable. Are there similar strings of words for the rest of the vowels?

Comment: Search under "minimal pairs lists".

Comment: Related: [The Chaos](http://ncf.idallen.com/english.html).

Comment: @AE that's great, not seen that before.

Answer (score 3):

For a Southern Standard British English accent, the following words would work:

**Short vowels**

- bid
- bed
- bad
- bod
- pud <sup>*</sup>
- bud

**Long vowels**

- bead
- booed
- bard
- board
- bird

**Diphthongs**

- bayed
- bide
- Boyd
- bowed (ribbon)
- bowed (genuflected)
- beard
- bared

<sup>*as in short for *pudding*</sup>

These cover the RP/SSBE vowels minus the schwa. Unfortunately there's no word with /b/ and /d/ like this containing the FOOT vowel. However /p/, being a bilabial plosive is quite close to /b/ and probably the best substitute, yielding the word *pud*. If we needed a monosyllabic word which normally has a schwa, we could use the weak form of *but*, /bət/. This doesn't end in a /d/, but similarly to the above, /t/ is the unvoiced partner of /d/, so is probably the best substitute.

---

<sup>This list is mostly cannibalised from *Gimson's Pronunciation of English*, 7th Edition, 2002.</sup>

Comment: Does nobody but me pronounce *bade* and *bad* as homophones? [See dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bade). *Bayed* would be less ambiguous.

Comment: @PeterShor Not in RP they don't. But, I believe, *bayed* and *bad* would also be homophones in some varieties!

Comment: @PeterShor Oh, you mean that way round! I see. Have amended.

Answer (score 1):

If one looks only at the first two formants of the vowels, then there are only two dimensions to wander through; but if one looks at the muscles then there are three dimensions (jaw: open..close, tongue: front..back, lips: stretched..rounded) so there is more of a 'stagger' to the lists.

For example, your list could be two lists: (bad, bed, bid) and (bad, bade, bead). {Note that 'bad' can be pronounced with or without stretching [smiling] of the lips}

More lists: (Bach, buck, book) (bought, boat, boot)

Answer (score 1):

Robertson Davies, in *The Lyre of Orpheus*, gives the following sentence with what he claims are the twelve English vowels:

> Who knows ought of art must learn,
>   And then take his ease.

Of course, this may be Canadian English, given Robertson Davies' nationality. Also, the vowel of *book* seems conspicuously absent.

Comment: +1 It rather assumes a STRAP vowel for *and* and a LOT vowel for *of*.

Comment: @Araucaria: now that you mention it, that has to be right. So this is RP. And the singer who gives this advice in the novel seems to be British.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be, or if it's a mistake. If it's RP, they've included the eleven  monopthongs apart from schwa, but included the FACE diphthong, for some unknown reason. I thought is was probably Canadian ..., but who knows?

Comment: @Araucaria: In the novel, these are sung vowels, not spoken vowels. I have no idea whether opera singers were supposed to use a monophthong for the FACE vowel in the mid-20th century, but my impression is that in singing, monophthongs are believed to sound better.

Comment: But which monophthong would it be?

Comment: The vowels in the second line would be [æ], [ɛ], [e], [ɪ], [i], very nicely arranged in order of increasing height (I'm leaving off the length marks because length is no longer distinguishable when singing). As I said, I have no idea whether mid-20th century opera singers were supposed to make /eɪ/ a monophthong. I don't think these are Canadian vowels, because LOT, CAUGHT, and FATHER are merged in Canada.

Comment: Actually, Googling shows that Robertson Davies seems to have misremembered the mnemonic. The original sentence was *who would know aught of art must learn and then take his ease*, which contains the BOOK vowel.